# The Hamiltoninian function always verifies $H(-p,q)=H(p,q)$?

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian

Is it true that the Hamiltoninian function of a system always verifies $H(-p,q)=H(p,q)$? If $H$ is the sum of the potential energy plus the kinetic energy then it seems true. But is there a possible case where this does not hold?

Comment: Magnetic fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can take a free particle, with $T = \frac{1}{2} m \dot{x}^2$ & $U = 0$, and redefine our coordinates so that $x \equiv q + u t$ for some constant $u$.  In terms of these new coordinates, it works out that $\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2} m (\dot{q} - u)^2$, and that
$$
\mathcal{H} = \frac{p^2}{2m} + p u.
$$
This Hamiltonian does not have the desired symmetry under $p \to - p$.

Answer (score 4):

It is not true in the case of the electromagnetic Hamiltonian for a charged particle in an electromagnetic field:
$$H = \frac{(\mathbf{p}-q\, \mathbf{A})^2}{2m} + q\phi, $$
where $\mathbf{A}$ is the vector (Magnetic) potential, $\phi$ is the scalar (Electric) potential, and $q$ and $m$ are the particle's charge and its mass, respectively.

Similarly, you could construct Hamiltonians in other scenarios possibly involving other forces that do not have ''even parity'' with respect to momentum.